# Create Drag and Drop Editing Platform in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am in the process of thinking how I should approach this feature that I want in my application. Basically, I want my users to be able to create custom pages, and those pages would be save to later be seen. But, I want to have a unified structure and feel. I also want it to be painless and very simple. I know I could be using something like TinyMCE, but sometimes the formatting can be a pain.

Here is a small sketch of what I would like:

[image: Sketch]

Something like http://www.diagram.ly/ but for text content. Ideally, once the user is done editing the page, I would simply save the content in XML, with tags representing each content type and apply styling accordingly once being rendered.

Is that too complicated, or something much simpler already exists? I would prefer using HTML5 if possible... but I am open to any suggestions or even other alternatives!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Have you ever looked at [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)?  That in conjunction with jquery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) should allow you to do what you want.

I used it in a custom lightweight content editor.  Works very well.  If I ever revisit that project, or do something similar I would create pre-configured draggable content sections so web neophytes could customize their pages even more.

Answer (score 5):

Looked a bit around after opening a bounty. Perhaps using the [atom text editor](https://atom.io/) to make markdown and using a [markdown preview](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) could be a way to do it? Then you could use some tool like [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert the markdown to xml.

I know it is not drag and drop, but it's better than M$ word.

Answer (score 5):

[medium-editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) seems to be a well-managed clone of the really great editor found on [Medium](https://medium.com/) whose [architectural principles are explained in here](https://medium.com/medium-eng/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480).

The solution here would do away with the drag & drop idea. Instead, the user selects any bit of text and then sees a toolbar pop up, allowing them to do any formatting they need. That [toolbar can be customized](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#toolbar-options) to suit your end-users' needs.

In the end, you get a well-formed (X)HTML string that's nice and clean. In order to do your styling, you could simply inject a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/some/file.css" />`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sean9999/ut7mk5x5/6/

```js
;(function(w,d,undeinfed){
    "use strict";
    d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        var e = d.querySelector('.editable'); // editable div
        var o = d.querySelector('#o'); // debug output
        var f = d.querySelector('#f'); // form
        var editor = new MediumEditor(e);
        var saveDocument = function(htmlfragments){
            var article = '<article>' + htmlfragments + '</article>';
            //    issue an AJAX call with "article" as the payload
            alert( article.replace(/\s{2,}/g,'') );
        };
        f.addEventListener('submit',function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            saveDocument(e.innerHTML);
        });
        editor.subscribe('editableInput', function (event, editable) {
            o.textContent = e.innerHTML;
        });
        o.textContent = e.innerHTML;
    });
})(window,document);
```

```css
h1 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: small;
}
article {
    border: 3px dotted rgba(255,0,0,.2);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0333);
    padding: 1em;
}
button {
    font-size: bigger;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: .5em;
}
.editable {
    outline: none;
}
output {
    border: 3px dotted rgba(0,0,255,0.25);
    margin-top: 1em;
    min-height: 5em;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/bower_components/medium-editor/dist/css/medium-editor.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/bower_components/medium-editor/dist/css/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/medium-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>

<section>
    <article>
        <div class="editable">
            <h2>Edit me, I'm a heading.</h2>
            <p>Edit me too, Chambray letterpress Godard meh, Echo Park slow-carb post-ironic whatever farm-to-table. Sriracha disrupt retro 90's, quinoa deep v Vice migas freegan pickled tattooed. Fashion axe meggings small batch, scenester Carles banh mi Shoreditch salvia.</p>
        </div>        
    </article>
</section>

<form name="f" id="f" action="#">
    <button type="submit">save the document</button>
</form>

<output for="f" id="o"></output>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try hammerJS, I think it can help you

http://hammerjs.github.io/